# How to find unicode character in text?

Tags: unicode, sublimetext3, non-ascii-characters, unicode-string

How can we find any Unicode control character(U+001D 0x1d ) in sublime text or any text editor in mac?

list of control character
https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=512&utf8=0x

Comment: Same way you would find any other character.  Being Unicode doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MarkRansom these characters are invisible